# Why is variable within command substitution within "bash -c" not visible?

Tags: bash

I need to run a command inside a `bash -c "..."` construct.  The actual command calls the [Vault CLI tool](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/) to generate a TLS certificate.  The important thing to note is that the CLI tool requires that a variable called `VAULT_TOKEN` be set.

For the sake of this example, assume that there are files in the local directory called `token` and `options`, with data that Vault requires.  These are not relevant to the question.

My script:

```
/bin/bash -c "export VAULT_TOKEN=$(cat token); \
    CERT_OPTIONS=$(cat options); \
    CERT=\"$(echo \$CERT_OPTIONS | vault write pki/issue/default -format=json -)\"; \
    echo cert=\$CERT"
```

The last statement in the command (`echo cert=\$CERT`) is simply a placeholder to demonstrate the problem, normally I would make use the value of `$CERT`.

My understanding of how the above should work (based on a very imperfect knowledge of Bash):

1. Bash is called and treats the contents of the `"..."` string as a script.  That script will then action the below:
2. Get the token from the file called `token`, export this value into a variable so that sub-processes can access it (hence the use of `export`).
3. Get the options from a file and put into a shell variable that is visible at the scope of the contents of the `bash -c` script.
4. Launch a separate process via command substitution that will call Vault, and `$VAULT_TOKEN` should be visible to this process as it is a child process of  the script that `bash -c` runs.

What I see, however, is an error that indicates that `$VAULT_TOKEN` is not set, i.e. the `vault` CLI tool throws an error saying it doesn't have a value for `$VAULT_TOKEN`.

When I simplify the command further to be:

```
/bin/bash -c "export VAULT_TOKEN=$(echo token); \
    CERT=\"$(echo \$VAULT_TOKEN > /tmp/test.out)\"; \
    echo cert=\$CERT"
```

I can see:

```
> cat /tmp/test.out
$VAULT_TOKEN
```

...not `token` that I was expecting.

I escaped the echo of `VAULT_TOKEN` (via `echo \$VAULT_TOKEN`), because otherwise I believe that it will be replaced by Bash with the value of `$VAULT_TOKEN` from my shell (which is not set), so I get an empty string in `/tmp/test.out`.

Clearly my understanding of command substitution/variable evaluation is wrong - please can someone advise on the below:

1. Why is `$VAULT_TOKEN` not visible in the `$(...)` command substitution?
2. How do I make `$VAULT_TOKEN` visible to the `vault` command?

For other reasons, I must run this set of commands in a `bash -c` manner, so I can't separate out the commands into a script.

Comment: The commands are not evaluated by the bash you start but by your shell. Try replacing bash -c "..." with bash -c '...'

Comment: `CERT="$(echo $VAULT_TOKEN > test.out)"`  CERT will be empty because you are redirecting the output to `test.out`.  Otherwise, replace the outer double quotes with single quotes and remove the \ escapes before each `$`.

Comment: @yaccz Thanks, that's exactly the issue.

Comment: You *never* need to change your code's quoting for `bash -c` use manually -- let the shell do that for you. `mycode() { code "with" 'unmodified' "quoting"; }; bash -c "$(declare -f mycode); mycode"`